# how to call html id from servlet class?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, servlets

I design one login page in **HTML**, for database I used servlet class, if username & password is correct then I call home class id in html page , but I dont know how to call html id from servlet file. I am using one html file, login & home page logic is in one html file, So my problem is how to call home class of html file from servlet.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <style>
    .header{width: 100%;background-color: #8B008B;color: #fff;padding: 30px 0px;font-size: 30px;}
    .footer{position:fixed;bottom:0;width:100%;background-color:#8B008B;color:#fff;padding:10px 0;}

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" media="all" />
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="conainer">
                <div class="pull-left text-left col-md-6">
                    Bakers & More
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right text-right col-md-6">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Logged in as</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Logout</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 8%;border: 1px solid;background-color: #FFE4C4;padding:30px;">

                <form class="form-horizontal" name="login_form" action="checkUser" method="post" > 
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()">Sign in</button>
                      <br />
                      <div id="demo"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                      <a href="#" role="button">Forgot Paswaord</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" style="display:none;" id="home">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 2%;border: 1px solid;padding:30px;">
                <h3>Administrator</h3>
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>User Details</option>
                  <option>Create user</option>
                  <option>Show User</option>
                  <option>Update User</option>
                  <option>Delete User</option>
                </select><br />
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>Shop Details</option>
                  <option>Device</option>
                  <option>Product</option>
                  <option>Special Iems</option>
                  <option>Order</option>
                </select><br />
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>User Details</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
                </select><br />
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>Shop Details</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div>Copyright. All Rights Reserved</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x, text;

                // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
                x = document.getElementById("inputEmail3").value;

                // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
                if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
                    text = "Input not valid";
                } else {
                    text = "Input OK";
                }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTMLs don't have any such thing as a "home class".